# Cannot run Google Home assistant routines by conversation relay

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm using google assistant relay (https://github.com/greghesp/assistant-relay/) on Raspberry PI. My objective is to allow my automation (jeedom) server to run Google actions. For basic instructions, everything is ok, such as switch on the light of a room. But when trying to run a Google Home routine command (for example, "lunch time" that should light on living room, light off tv room) assistant doesn't run routine but answer such as if routine was not existing, for example it tries to search for a restaurant named "lunch time".

I registered a device (obtaining model id and device id) and put reference of this device in the relay system but it does not work better, same result.

In Google Home app, I set for this device permission to execute with personal data but same result.

I expect to launch routines with my relay in order to allow my jeedom server to put some advanced tasks to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Developer of Assistant Relay here.

I'm not sure if the triggering Routines is a SDK limitation or not.  Some people seem to have had success with Hass.io's integration, however I've not managed to get it to work (not looked into it too much)

I'm working on V3 so will see if I can get it working